# GTM - Table - Click on a button, and get the text of another selector

Tags: javascript, onclicklistener, google-tag-manager

I am not a developer but I am trying to get hand in hand with Google Tag Manager.
I am working for some people that they want to track a button click on a search result.
So, you'd get the 10 products, with the name, description and a Sample button.
I can track the button on GTM (that's the easy bit), but I need to assign the button click to each product name.

This is the bit of HTML that I want to work on:

```
    <tr>
    <td>
        <p class="category">
                Product 
        </p>
            <a href="/sector/product/123456789"><img class="search_image" src="https://example.com/medium/123456789.jpg" alt="Name of the Product" onerror="this.src='system/images/company_logo_block.jpg'" /> 
             </a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <h3><a href="/sector/product/123456789">Name of the product</a></h3>
        <p>Benefits of the product explained</p>
        <p>Material <b>Plastic</b></p>
        <div class="button_container">
            <div class="action_container">
                <div class="action_trigger">
                    <input type="hidden" id="code_123456789" name="code" value="123456789" />
                    <label class="visible" for="quantity_123456789">Quantity</label><br />
                    <input class="search_result_quantity numeric_only" id="quantity_123456789" name="quantity" type="number" value="1" 
                        onkeydown="return isValidInput(this, 5, event);"/>
                    <label for="add_to_basket_123456789">Add to basket</label>
                    <input class="add_sample search_result_action" id="add_to_basket_123456789" name="add_to_basket" type="submit" value="Add to basket" />
                </div>
                <div class="action_response">
                    <img src="/sector/system/images/loading.gif" alt="Loading" />
                </div>
                <div class="action_result">
                    <img src="/sector/system/images/tick.jpg" alt="Success" /><span>Added.</span><a href="/sector/basket/">View basket</a>
 </div>
<label for="get_sample">Get a Sample</label><input class="add_sample search_result_action" name="Sample_product" type="button"  value="Sample Product" onclick="window.location='http://www.samplepage.com/123456789';"/>
                <div class="clearer"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <p123456789</p>
        <p>
            Online
             &#124; 24/09/2015
        </p>
        <p><strong>Price:&nbsp;&nbsp;&pound;26.99  +VAT</strong></p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

So, when a user clicks on the button "Sample Product", I would like to grab the name of the product, which sits on the top `<tr>` with the tag h3.
For each product, there is a `<tr>` where all the information sits

On the console, I can get the "nodes" with document.querySelectorAll ("tr td h3)[0] - or [1] or [2] according to the name of the product I want.

I now can't get a function that, onClick a Button, will return me the `<h3>` text of that `<tr>` selector. Is this even possible?

Thanks so much for your help.
George

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("tr td h3")[0].value`?

Comment: Thanks zevee! But I use that line in a JS variable? I need (or at least I think I need) a JS function that allows me to retrieve the name of the product, every time I click on the button "Get a Sample". 
From my parse knowledge, I think I would need something like, when onclik on this button, search the tree up to the <tr> selector and return the innerText of it. But I can't program it, or at least my knowledge doesn't go that far...

Comment: `function getASample() {return document.querySelectorAll("tr td h3")[0].value}`? StackOverflow doesn't code for you

Answer (score 0):

Ok. After long hours of trial and error, I came up with a solution that works.
I'll leave it here in case it might help someone.

```
function() {
var els = document.querySelectorAll('[value="Sample Product"]'); 
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i += 1) { 
if (els[i] === {{Click Element}}) { 
    var elsname = document.querySelectorAll('tr td h3')[i].innerText
return elsname; }
}
return elsname;
}
```